# Remove a specific link using PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

what is the best way to replace a string like this using preg_replace:

```
<a class="left" href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>
```

It is an exact string that appears in many places, and I need it gone. I have tried `preg_replace('#<a class="left" href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>#','',$str);`

and `preg_replace('#<a class="left" href="javascript:goBack\\(\\)">Back<\\/a>#','',$str)` but no joy.

any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to use `preg_replace` if you know the exact string you want to match. Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$str=str_replace('<a class="left" href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>','', $str);
```

Comment: Hi guys,I got the impression that str_replace may be phased out, is this not the case?

Comment: @Liam Bailey Not at all. Somebody completely misunderstood something. str_replace is a core method and will almost certainly stay forever. Google codesearch alone can find 280000 scripts that use it, so removing it would lead to greater incompatibilities than updating from php3 to php6.

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a reason to use `preg_replace` instead of `str_replace`, try this:

```
preg_replace('#\Q<a class="left" href="javascript:goBack()">Back</a>\E#','',$str);
```

That will cause any metacharacters (like the `(` and `)` in the string :-) ) to be treated as normal characters devoid of their special meanings.